# call a method from an object in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, class, object

```
 export class MockedDataService {
    constructor(private Session: SessionService) {}

    private getMocked(name:string){
       return ""; // return whatever result is, will be a promise
    }


    public mocked:{
           products:{
              getAllProducts: function(){return this.getMocked("")},
              getProductByType: function(type){return this.getMocked(type)}
           }

    }
}
```

Now if this class is injected in a component, then you can call this service as

```
this.MockedDataService.mocked.products.getAllProducts().then((result) => { 
  console.log(result);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log("error: ",err.message);        
});
```

Then an error is raised: "this.getMocked is not a function"
a fix for that issue is to change the code to :

`getAllProducts: function(){return ()=> this.getMocked("")}`

But this fix will raise another error: 
"this.MockedDataService.mocked.products.getAllProducts().then is not a function"

Comment: Also note that it is very unconventional to store methods inside of properties of a service... Why not just define getMocked on the service itself? The `then is not a function` error is because whatever you returned is not a promise.

Answer (score 1):

You have lost your context afterthe 
`getAllProducts: function(){return this.getMocked("")}` assignment.

You need to use the arrow function higher on one level or bind the context explicitly

`getAllProducts: () => { return this.getMocked(""); }`

For shorter, just

`getAllProducts: () => this.getMocked("")`

Comment: that will work, but how can i pass the function parameter in

 getProductByType: function(type){return this.getMocked(type)}

Comment: Pass parameter to the arrow - `getProductByType: (type) => this.getMocked(type)`

Comment: So in the class should look like this 
public mocked:{
           products:{
              getAllProducts: ()=>this.getMocked(""),
              getProductByType:(type)this.getMocked(type)
           }
    }
works fine

Comment: Thank you for your help, that was fast and fine, how can I skip mocked function when call this service, I mean change this: 
 `this.MockedDataService.mocked.products.getAllProducts()`
to this:
 `this.MockedDataService.products.getAllProducts()`
in Javascript we could export the whole object like this 
`return {
           products:{
              getAllProducts: function(){return this.getMocked("")},
              getProductByType: function(type){return this.getMocked(type)}
           }`

Comment: Instead of the `mock` just have it's content

Comment: I thought that would be equal to javascript return whole function, but that worked fine and thank you again,

Comment: @M.E. If the answer helped you, can you accept it?